# Reduce a JavaScript array into named objects

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

The code below reduces an array into "named" objects (not sure if that's the correct terminology!)

It works, but I'm sure the code could be improved. There is some repetition going on in the reduce.

It checks if a key exists (`if (accumulator[name])`). If not then initialize the `results` array, if it does then push onto the `results` array.

```
let response = {
  columns: [
    'n'
  ],
  data: [
    {
      graph: {
        nodes: [
          {
            id: '169',
            labels: [
              'Container'
            ],
            properties: {
              reference: 'REF002',
              name: 'Cupboard',
              id: '003'
            }
          }
        ],
        relationships: []
      }
    },
    {
      graph: {
        nodes: [
          {
            id: '170',
            labels: [
              'Container'
            ],
            properties: {
              reference: 'REF003',
              name: 'Cupboard A',
              id: '03a'
            }
          }
        ],
        relationships: []
      }
    },
    {
      graph: {
        nodes: [
          {
            id: '964',
            labels: [
              'Equipment'
            ],
            properties: {
              reference: 'REF004',
              name: 'Cupboard B',
              id: '03b'
            }
          }
        ],
        relationships: []
      }
    }
  ]
}

const result = response.data.reduce(
  (accumulator, currentValue, currentIndex, array) => {
    const name = currentValue.graph.nodes[0].labels[0];

    if (accumulator[name]) {
      accumulator[name].results.push({
        title: currentValue.graph.nodes[0].properties.name,
        description: currentValue.graph.nodes[0].properties.reference
      });
    } else {
      accumulator[name] = {
        name,
        results: [
          {
            title: currentValue.graph.nodes[0].properties.name,
            description: currentValue.graph.nodes[0].properties.reference
          }
        ]
      };
    }

    return accumulator;
  },
  {}
);

console.clear();
console.log(result);
```

*Output Required*

```
{
  Container: {
    name: 'Container',
    results: [
      {
        title: 'Cupboard',
        description: 'REF002'
      },
      {
        title: 'Cupboard A',
        description: 'REF003'
      }
    ]
  },
  Foo: {
    name: 'Foo',
    results: [
      {
        title: 'Cupboard B',
        description: 'REF004'
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it looks like you are using ES6 syntax, you could also throw in some destructuring assignments, but I guess the main point is that one would need to create the output object only once. One could also extract the accumulation into a descriptive name:

```
byFirstLabel = (acc, {graph: {nodes: [node]}}) => {
  let label = node.labels[0]
  let { name: title, reference: description } = node.properties
  let entry = { title, description }

  acc[label] ? acc[label].results.push(entry) :
    acc[label] = { name: label, results: [ entry ] }

  return acc
}

response.data.reduce(byFirstLabel, {})
```

Comment: Excellent, I didn't know you could rename while destructuring an object.  Could you explain what's going on in {graph: {nodes: [node]}} ? I think you're destructing the object as it's coming into the loop, but not sure exactly what magic is happening there:)

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Nested_object_and_array_destructuring AND https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Assigning_to_new_variable_names

Answer (score 1):

You could try this. Keep the `push` logic as the only way to add `results` and separate out the initialisation logic to the `||` condition before itself

```js
let response = {
  columns: [
    'n'
  ],
  data: [{
      graph: {
        nodes: [{
          id: '169',
          labels: [
            'Container'
          ],
          properties: {
            reference: 'REF002',
            name: 'Cupboard',
            id: '003'
          }
        }],
        relationships: []
      }
    },
    {
      graph: {
        nodes: [{
          id: '170',
          labels: [
            'Container'
          ],
          properties: {
            reference: 'REF003',
            name: 'Cupboard A',
            id: '03a'
          }
        }],
        relationships: []
      }
    },
    {
      graph: {
        nodes: [{
          id: '964',
          labels: [
            'Equipment'
          ],
          properties: {
            reference: 'REF004',
            name: 'Cupboard B',
            id: '03b'
          }
        }],
        relationships: []
      }
    }
  ]
}

const result = response.data.reduce(
  (accumulator, currentValue, currentIndex, array) => {
    // Create a node const to avoid repeating it
    const node = currentValue.graph.nodes[0];
    const name = node.labels[0];
    // Move initialization logic here
    accumulator[name] = accumulator[name] || {
      name,
      results: []
    };

    // There is no need for the previous check anymore
    accumulator[name].results.push({
      title: node.properties.name,
      description: node.properties.reference
    });

    return accumulator;
  }, {}
);

console.clear();
console.log(result);
```